# How do I use these Unity math functions in Godot C#?

Tags: unity, mathematics, vector, godot, linear-algebra

Here's a list of math functions I'm having trouble finding a direct function match for in Godot C#:

```
math.rcp() //get reciprocal of a float
//Then there's swizzle operations like:
float4 point;
float4 newpoint = point.yzwx;
```

There's also all sorts of other vector operations I can't find the equivalent for like:

```
float3 point;
math.abs(point);
math.exp(point);
```

Also I need certain special vector types like:

```
uint3 point //Is like an unsigned int vec3
```

Also in this code that I'm converting it adds a float to a float3 and I'm not even sure what the semantics are for that.

```
float3 add
add * 0.6f + 0.5f;
```

This is the code I'm trying to convert https://github.com/aras-p/UnityGaussianSplatting/blob/main/package/Runtime/GaussianUtils.cs
I've been able to reproduce all of the functions with constructors and changing rcp to 1.0f/x, but I don't know what the memory allocations will do to the performance.
These are my questions, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question comes from [Unity.Mathematics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mathematics@1.0/manual/index.html).

This is a relatively independent package that does not depend much on other parts of Unity. So we can simply refer to the source code to make a version for godot c#.

[Source code of Unity.Mathematics](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/Unity.Mathematics/tree/master)

> math.rcp(); math.abs(point); math.exp(point);

They are all in [math.cs](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/Unity.Mathematics/blob/master/src/Unity.Mathematics/math.cs).

> float4 point;

It's in [float4.gen.cs](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/Unity.Mathematics/blob/master/src/Unity.Mathematics/float4.gen.cs).

> float4 newpoint = point.yzwx;

They created different versions of swizzles using code generation, e.g.

```
/// <summary>Swizzles the vector.</summary>
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public float4 yzwx
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    get { return new float4(y, z, w, x); }
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    set { y = value.x; z = value.y; w = value.z; x = value.w; }
}
```

> add * 0.6f + 0.5f;

They use [operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading) to implement various operations between float4 and float, e.g.

```
/// <summary>Returns the result of a componentwise addition operation on a float value and a float4 vector.</summary>
/// <param name="lhs">Left hand side float to use to compute componentwise addition.</param>
/// <param name="rhs">Right hand side float4 to use to compute componentwise addition.</param>
/// <returns>float4 result of the componentwise addition.</returns>
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static float4 operator + (float lhs, float4 rhs) { return new float4 (lhs + rhs.x, lhs + rhs.y, lhs + rhs.z, lhs + rhs.w); }
```

Anyway, translating Unity code to Godot C# is not a simple API switch. Depending on the situation, you can implement a method yourself or create a replacement for a package yourself. It's a lot easier when you have a ready-made package as a reference.

P.S. [LICENSE of Unity package source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/Unity.Mathematics/blob/master/LICENSE.md)

Comment: Note that the Unity Companion License says that you may only use that code in a Unity project. Copying that library into a Godot project would probably work (because the library appears to be nothing but vanilla C# code with no dependencies on the Unity API), but it would  probably a copyright violation.

Answer (score 2):

> math.rcp() //get reciprocal of a float

As far as I know godot has no ready-made `rpc` method. All mathematical methods of godot are placed in [globalscope](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_%40globalscope.html). You can check if a method is implemented.

> Vector4 newpoint = point.yzwx;

Pretty sure this swizzle syntax doesn't come from godot or unity or c#. It comes from a shading language.

> math.abs(point);

`abs` is implemented as a member function of vector, see [class_vector2](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector2.html):

```
var absPoint = point.Abs();
```

> math.exp(point);

[Exp(float)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Exp.html) returns e raised to the specified power. It does not accept a vector parameter. This is also implemented in globalscope.

> uint3 point //Is like an unsigned int vec3

See [c_sharp_variant](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/c_sharp/c_sharp_variant.html). Here are Vector2I, Vector3I and Vector4I.

> add * 0.6f + 0.5f;

Pretty sure this code comes from a shading language too. The OpenGL Shading Language specification says:

> One operand is a scalar, and the other is a vector or matrix. In this case, the scalar operation is applied independently to each component of the vector or matrix, resulting in the same size vector or matrix.

Where Godot is lacking convenience methods, you can build your own. For instance, a quick search brings up the [Unity docs for `rcp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mathematics@1.3/api/Unity.Mathematics.math.rcp.html) which says that when `n` is a vector the result is a componentwise reciprocal. The reciprocal of `n` is `1.0/n`. Applying that to a `Vector2` would give you something like:

```
public static Vector2 rcp(Vector2 v)
{
   return new Vector3(1.0/v.x, 1.0/v.y);
}
```

Comment: This is the code I'm trying to convert https://github.com/aras-p/UnityGaussianSplatting/blob/main/package/Runtime/GaussianUtils.cs I don't know the codebase well enough to know if using int instead of uint would be fine with all the bitshifting, I also don't know how to implement the OpenGL Shading language into Godot C# Scripting. I don't know how they put a float3 inside a math.exp on line 22. I also don't know if a custom reciprocal or custom swizzle (new constructor) would work the same as the existing code. But if you could let me know? Also thank you for the Abs function I missed.

Comment: @Mangata I figured adding an edit to your answer to address the comment made more sense than splitting the info off into another answer. Feel free to edit further as needed.

Comment: @Mangata the shader-like stuff is from the Unity.Mathematics package. It is often used to write shader-like code that runs on the cpu using the unity job system.

Comment: @Jack Thanks for your reminder. You are right, the code in the question comes from Unity.Mathematics. I am not familiar with this package, so my answer was misleading. Anyway, translating Unity code to Godot C# is not a simple API switch, I will add a more accurate answer for this particular case.